# Change players health based on scoreboard objectives

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a custom map in which I have a scoreboard objective. Is there any way to change a player's health based on this scoreboard objective? The only thing I could find was putting a button on a player's head with the max health attribute but that has many disadvantages.

Comment: Do you want to change the maximal life the player can gain or just set its number of hearts (would regenerate normally)?

Comment: Gameryle natural regeneration false.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this, since health is a read-only attribute.

Answer (score -1):

1st: /scoreboard objectives add [name] health [display name]

*Add any name to name and display name*

2nd: /scoreboard objectives setdisplay belowname [name]

*Set the name you want to display at the scoreboard at name*

(Your health will show up as 0 until you lose some...it's a bug)

Comment: Your solution does the opposite of what I asked for. I have an objective with a number in it and I want to set a players health to that number

Comment: I have a dummy objective, and I want to change the player life based on that.

Answer (score -1):

This is going to need a lot of command blocks.

Command 1: /scoreboard objectives add health health [Display Name of Objective]

Command 2: /scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar health

Command 3: /scoreboard objectives add hea health

Okay, this command is going to need to be in a loop.

/testfor @a[score_health_min:20,score_health:20]

(Put a compartor here)

/effect @a[score_health_min:20,score_health:20] minecraft:regeneration 2 255

Now, make another loop.

/testfor @a[score_health_min:18,score_health:18]

(Compartor)

/scoreboard players set @a[score_health_min:18,score_health:18] hea 18

Another loop:

/testfor @a[score_health_min:16,score_health:16]

(Compartor)

/scoreboard players set @a[score_health_min:16,score_health:16] hea 16

---

Continue this, counting down by 2 every time and adjusting accordingly.

Comment: There are a number of problems with this. The "health" objective-type cannot be modified (as you're doing with the "hea" objective). Parameters separate keys and values with equals signs, not colons. What is the `/effect` command doing; the player is already at full health, so why is it there? Setting a score does not actually modify the player's health. Why in increments of 2 rather than 1?